# Слитное и раздельное написание НЕ с причастиями

Tags: частица-не

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пишется страшное словосочетание "не импортозамещаемого в России"?

Comment: Alenka, а каков контекст?

Comment: Контекст не сильно сложный и вряд ли прояснит ситуацию: Вышел новый перечень импортного оборудования, не облагаемого НДС и не импортозамещаемого в России. Мало того, что фактически слово "импортозамещаемый" - новое. Так еще и с НЕ употреблено. По идее - слитно должно писаться...

Comment: _Alenka: Так еще и с НЕ употреблено._ === Если напишете раздельно, ошибки точно не будет. Но вот что может означать это слово _(импортозамещаемый)_, я пока понять не смог.

Comment: Речь идет о перечене технологического оборудования, _аналоги которого не производятся в России_. Т. е., как я понимаю, такие позиции, которые производятся за рубежом, и которые мы производить пока не можем. Так что ли.

Comment: А разве здесь не действует пресловутое уже правило про слова, на **-мый**, которые, не имея при себе зависимых слов в тв. падеже, пишутся слитно?

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае, как Вы указали, действует правило причастий и прилагательных на мый. Исходя из правила, здесь нужно слитное написание, т.к. нет зависимого слова в творительном падеже.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но, конечно, "неимпортозамещаемого" - уж больно страшное слово получается...

Comment: _Серж: "...действует правило причастий и прилагательных на мый"._ === Да **правило-то,** может, и **есть.** Вопрос в другом: **а слово-то** такое _("импортозамещаемый")_ **есть?** И если есть, отличается ли оно по значению от слова "импортозамещающий", употребляемого по отношению к отечественным товарам, производимым взамен импортных?

Comment: Слава,возможно слово новое, возможно, просто неправильное употребление. Я лишь ответил, что в не с данным словом пишется вместе. Поскольку в этом тексте это слово. Хотя в Интернете это слово можно встретить.

Comment: _Серж: "...возможно, просто неправильное употребление"._ === Я именно так и считаю.

Comment: Слава, к сожалению, в нашей стране нет возможности самому просматривать Гугл-книги, только по ссылкам могу пройтись. Я смотрел это слово в Яндексе.

Comment: Ваши ссылки работают.

Answer (score 2):

Есть возможность написать словосочетание раздельно, если считать, что НЕ относится ко всему словосочетанию:

Вышел новый перечень импортного оборудования, не (облагаемого НДС) и не (импортозамещаемого в России).

Слитное написание совершенно неудобно для чтения.

Правило

Отрицательная частица НЕ может относиться не только к слову, но и к словосочетанию,  в этом случае НЕ пишется всегда раздельно, например:

Она была бледна, но не (болезненно бледна). А разве воздействовать на людей не (великое искусство)? Да кто же не (среднего роста),  у кого не (русые волосы), не (прямой нос) да не (карие глаза). Воспоминания – это не (пожелтевшие  письма), не (засохшие цветы).

Comment: "Невеликое искусство – копировать чужие мысли". А тут к чему относится НЕ?!

Comment: Здесь два варианта решения, они различаются по смыслу: (1) Невеликое (простое) искусство – копировать чужие мысли. (2) Не (великое искусство) – копировать чужие мысли (т.е. не является великим искусством, при этом на первом слове делается логическое ударение).

Comment: Но второй вариант вполне можно посчитать за ошибку. Например, в школьном диктанте.

Comment: Так это обычное правило, из Розенталя, так и скажите своему учителю. Можно для убедительности стихи вспомнить, например: "Не простое это дело – топором махать умело".

Comment: У Розенталя есть такой пример?! Да ни в жизнь. А ваш пример совсем не из той оперы. Да, здесь возможно раздельное написание.

Comment: Рекомендации Лопатина: "Таким образом, пишущий должен отдавать себе отчет в том, что он хочет выразить: отрицание признака — и тогда написать НЕ отдельно от следующего слова (напр.: он не здоров, не важно, не редки случаи, не случайно, не существенно, не удивительно, НЕ ДЕМОКРАТИЧЕСКИМ ПУТЕМ) или утверждение признака — и тогда написать не слитно (ср.: он нездоров, нередки случаи, неважно, неслучайно, несущественно, неудивительно, НЕДЕМОКРАТИЧЕСКИМ ПУТЕМ). От выбора написания будет зависеть и понимание написанного читающими.

Comment: От себя могу добавить, что правила существуют для того, чтобы текст имел  ясную, понятную, красивую графику, а вовсе не для того, чтобы эти правила просто соблюдать, изображая на письме нечитаемые конструкции  (или не умея выбрать правильное оформление, править авторский вариант).

Comment: "Красивая графика" – этта што?! Что касается рекомендаций Лопатина, то кто же не знает, что если есть отрицание – пишем раздельно, нет отрицания – слитно. От себя могу добавить, что во многих случаях слитное написание просто невозможно: нет такого слова в языке, и всё. Поэтому сначала надо смотреть в словарях.

Comment: Красивая графика - это немногоэтажное слово с ясным значением, а в словари новые слова вносят лет через десять-двадцать.

Answer (score 1):

> Речь идет о перечне технологического оборудования, аналоги которого 
>   не производятся в России.

Тогда, может, так и написать:

***"Вышел новый перечень не облагаемого НДС импортного оборудования, аналоги которого не производятся в России"***?

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Хотя, конечно, лучше было бы указать именно то название перечня, которое он на самом деле имеет. Но я этот перечень  в Сети найти не смог.

Comment: Нашёл. См. http://docs.cntd.ru/document/902155270 : _Об утверждении перечня технологического оборудования (в том числе комплектующих и запасных частей к нему), **аналоги которого не производятся в Российской Федерации**, ввоз которого на территорию Российской Федерации не ... (с изменениями на 3 сентября **2015** года)_

Comment: Так что никакого **"импортозамещаемого"** в названии перечня просто-напросто нет. Ни со слитным, ни с раздельным  НЕ!

Comment: Это авторские слова в анонсе. Речь здесь и не идет о названии перечня. Но Ваш вариант действительно лучше.